# python: How can I determine the HID collections of a USB device on windows

Tags: python, windows

Is there a way to use python to determine the HID collections that a USB device supports on a windows system? I know the PID and VID if that helps.

Is there a python library that supports getting this information from a windows OS?

I want to see the information that is reported in a USB report descriptor, like TELEPHONY DEVICE PAGE (0X0B)  or  CONSUMER PAGE (0X0C) as listed in the “Universal Serial Bus HID Usage Tables” specification provided by usb.org. If I could see the report descriptor that is reported to the OS at enumeration (what I see on a USB bus analyzer), I could interpret this info myself.

**This information is also reported in windows "device manager" if there is a way to access that programmatically with python.**

**Here's a sample of info from windows "device manager" that I'm trying to get**

```
HID\VID_047F&PID_4304&REV_1030&MI_03&Col01
HID\VID_047F&PID_4304&MI_03&Col01
HID\VID_047F&UP:000C_U:0001
HID_DEVICE_SYSTEM_CONSUMER
HID_DEVICE_UP:000C_U:0001
HID_DEVICE
```

**here is another example, the vendor unique page 0xFFA2, collection 3**

```
HID\VID_047F&PID_4304&REV_1030&MI_03&Col03
HID\VID_047F&PID_4304&MI_03&Col03
HID\VID_047F&UP:FFA2_U:0003
HID_DEVICE_UP:FFA2_U:0003
HID_DEVICE_UPR:FF00-FFFF
HID_DEVICE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use devcon.exe from the windows development kit,

**C:\devcon find "usb\vid_047F&PID_4304*"**
USB\VID_047F&PID_4304\BF12A7512D7B4C59A247F46169EAC66C      : USB Composite Device
USB\VID_047F&PID_4304&MI_00\6&340A5046&1&0000               : Plantronics Blackwire 7225 Series
USB\VID_047F&PID_4304&MI_03\6&340A5046&1&0003               : USB Input Device

**C:>devcon find hid\vid_047F***

HID\VID_047F&PID_4304&MI_03&COL04\7&15B7B00&0&0003          : HID-compliant vendor-defined device
HID\VID_047F&PID_4304&MI_03&COL03\7&15B7B00&0&0002          : HID-compliant vendor-defined device
HID\VID_047F&PID_4304&MI_03&COL02\7&15B7B00&0&0001          : HID-compliant headset
HID\VID_047F&PID_4304&MI_03&COL01\7&15B7B00&0&0000          : HID-compliant consumer control device
HID\VID_047F&PID_E002\6&3449A104&1&0000                     : HID-compliant vendor-defined device

**and pipe the data into my python program for parsing like this,**

from subprocess import check_output

> > > x = check_output("devcon.exe find hid\vid_047F*", shell=True)